# Include if..else... statement in JS forEach method?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, foreach, syntax-error

While trying to update a dictionary inside the iterator I got the error "**SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'if'**"

The ut_frequencies data looks like:

```
{ "_id" : "app1", "cnt" : 3422 }
{ "_id" : "app2", "cnt" : 2752 }
{ "_id" : "app3", "cnt" : 2736 }
{ "_id" : "app4", "cnt" : 2711 }
```

Which I suppose is a list of dictionaries. I want to check if the app is already in the data dictionary and if so, update the "utf" value, if not, then add a new item only with the "utf" attribute set.

```
ut_frequencies.forEach(item=> 
  if(item._id in data){
    data[item._id]["utf"] = item.cnt;

  }else{
    data[item._id] = {utf: item.cnt, atf: 0, ptf: 0};
  }
)
```

Which is the best way to solve this.

Comment: You actually dont need the if/else yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that on the right of the arrow, an expression is expected.

An `if` condition is not an expression, therefore you should put braces around the body of the function.

```
ut_frequencies.forEach(item => {
    if(item._id in data){
        data[item._id]["utf"] = item.cnt;
    }else{
        data[item._id] = {utf: item.cnt, atf: 0, ptf: 0};
    }
});
```